# WinAPI MIDI input

Tags: winapi

I am using the Windows MIDI interface for communicating with my MIDI devices.
Everything works fine, also with system-exclusive messages as long as a SYSEX message is framed with `0xF0 <data> 0xF7`.

Well, I have an old Sampler (AKAI S900) which uses SYSEX without the `0xF7` at the end (common sample dump). My problem is, when the Sampler sends this string (`0xF0 <some data>`), I do not get it, because the Win32 API seems to wait for the trailing `0xF7` at the end of the SYSEX message.

How can I tell the MIDI interface to tell me immediately when a byte is available on the MIDI input, and not only when a complete message is received?

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
midiInOpen(&device_in,
   selected_midi_in_interface(DWORD_PTR)midi_in_callback,
   0, CALLBACK_FUNCTION);
    
...

midiHdr_in.lpData = temp_input;
midiHdr_in.dwBufferLength = (DWORD)input_len;
midiHdr_in.dwFlags = 0;

midiInPrepareHeader(device_in, &midiHdr_in, sizeof(MIDIHDR));

...

midiInAddBuffer(device_in, &midiHdr_in, sizeof(MIDIHDR));

midiInStart(device_in);

...

while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0){

  TranslateMessage(&Msg);
  DispatchMessage(&Msg);

  // Check if midiHdr_in.dwBytesRecorded has changed...
  ...
}
```

Comment: "The MM_MIM_LONGDATA message is sent to a window when either a complete MIDI system-exclusive message is received **or when a buffer has been filled with system-exclusive data.**"   So if you're really careful with your buffer size, you might get it to fill even though the system hasn't seen 0xF7.   Definitely sounds less than ideal.

Comment: I also tried this...he still waits for the trailing 0xF7...although my buffer is full already